# Firebase Cloud Functions - move data in Firestore

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Have a very basic understanding of the Typescript language, but would like to know, how can I copy multiple documents from one firestore database collection to another collection?

I know how to send the request from the app's code along with the relevant data (a string and firebase auth user ID), but unsure about the Typescript code to handle the request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats a very broad question, but something like this can move data in moderate sizes from one collection to another:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';   
import {firestore} from 'firebase-admin';

export async function moveFromCollection(collectionPath1: string, collectionPath2: string): void {
    try {
        const collectionSnapshot1Ref = firestore.collection(collectionPath1);
        const collectionSnapshot2Ref = firestore.collection(collectionPath2);

        const collectionSnapshot1Snapshot = await collectionSnapshot1Ref.get();
        // Here we get all the snapshots from collection 1. This is ok, if you only need
        // to move moderate amounts of data (since all data will be stored in memory)
        // Now lets use lodash chunk, to insert data in batches of 500
        const chunkedArray = _.chunk(collectionSnapshot1Snapshot.docs, 500);
        // chunkedArray is now an array of arrays, with max 500 in each
        for (const chunk of chunkedArray) {
            const batch  = firestore.batch();
            // Use the batch to insert many firestore docs
            chunk.forEach(doc => {
                // Now you might need some business logic to handle the new address,
                // but maybe something like this is enough
                const newDocRef = collectionSnapshot2Ref.doc(doc.id);
                batch.set(newDocRef, doc.data(), {merge: false});
            });
            await batch.commit();
            // Commit the batch
        }
        console.log('Done!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`something went wrong: ${error.message}`);
    }
}
```

But maybe you can tell more about the use case?

Comment: Apologies, my unfamiliarity with node/typescript lead to a broad question. 

On http request from the app, I'd like to copy <10 docs from a Firestore collection "users/{userID}/dogs", and write those docs into another collection "data/{stringID}/checkedDogs"...
With that naming convention following collection/document/collection.

Once the docs have been written to the new collection, I'd like to notify the user.

I'll then use a separate function to later remove the same documents on request.

Comment: The first part, moving docs and notify the user when done, is simple. You just call the https function from your app, and wait for the promise to fulfill. When the promise resolve, you inform the user! You will need authentication for this, so depending on your client, you could maybe use callable functions (that solves the authentication), or just authenticate the HTTPS request like showed here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint

Comment: Reading over my comment and your code example, I'm sure I can tweak it to fit the situation... But now I wonder if it's even worth trying to handle the request via cloud functions. I have a current working solution to get a collection snapshot and write it to the other collection within the app, but I was hoping cloud functions could be used to spare some read/write events from being consumed

Comment: Hmm - I mean if its only 10 docs, you could def just do it in the app. Firestore functions won't save you read/write events from being consumed(!). Normally you would do this with functions, if the user in the app for example does not have write access to the destination, or other stuff (secret business logic), making it impossible to do on the client. But if its only 10 docs, and the user has permissions, I would also do it client side.

Comment: My bad, incorrect assumption of the read/write situation... Data isn't secret, yet, but may decide to remove write permissions in the future. Still, your answer is quite helpful if I ever have to come back to it. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you do if, for example, chunk 1 succeeds, chunk 2 fails, and chunk 3 succeeds? How do you handle chunk 2 failing (right now there is just an error message being logged).

Comment: Then you should wrap the batch commit in a try catch. What do you wan't to to if it fails - try again?

Comment: Yes, I worry of infinite retries in that case. I suppose you can set a limit on retries, even then you could run into a case where it fails for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes that is true. You should probably report a serious error to your error handling system, if an unexpected error is thrown and then act on it. But I am running hundreds of batch commits (serverside), and my experience is that they work very well.